# Php mysql update value into first free column of row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row with 8 columns, I want to update the first empty column cell. 
I'm guessing I would have to loop through each column and check to see if any come back null. Am I looking in the right direction?

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE Table SET firstemptycell = ?");
```

Comment: UPDATE Table SET firstemptycell = 'value' where firstemptycell = ''

Comment: no, doesn't sound like it. Sounds like you took the wrong direction when designing your table layout